# Проблема вызова метода базового класса у класса потомка

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование, множественное-наследование

Такая проблема: сделал множественное наследование, хочу у класса C, который наследует функционал класса В,  вызвать метод "base.GetSeats()" класса A, который в свою очередь является базовым для класса В, но так как С наследник В, то он его определяет как базовый.
Подскажите пожалуйста **как я могу реализовать вызов метода класса А в классе С, не прибегая к созданию экземпляра класса A и не изменяя наследования С от В?**

P.s. только начинаю познавать C#, поэтому не судите строго если как-то не в особо понятной форме излагаю свои мысли, пример ниже это упрощенный вариант основной задачи, в которой у каждого из классов свой уникальный функционал.

```
public class A
{
    public int a = 0;
    public virtual void GetSeats()
    {
      a = 10;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void GetSeats()
    {
      base.GetSeats(); //тут вызывается метод класса А
      a *= 2;
    }
}

public class С : В
{
    public virtual void GetSeats()
    {
      base.GetSeats(); //тут вызывается метод класса В, а мне надо, чтоб вызывался метод А
      a *= 5; // то есть проще говоря тут будет a = 100, а мне нужно чтобы эта переменная бралась из класса А, а не В
    }
}
```

Comment: подобные проблемы говорят о проблеме в архитектуре. Класс C вообще не должен ничего знать о том, от чего наследуется класс В. Каждый класс по идее должен быть озабочен только собой и своим родителем.

Comment: Слишком абстрактно всё. Тут скорее надо знать реальную тему, что в реальности строится. Т.к. мозжножно класс C тоже должен наследоваться от A.....А может тут должен быть применён какой-то паттерн. Так что в текущем случае ничего сказать нельзя, только то, что так делать бессмысленно

Comment: _у каждого из классов свой уникальный функционал_ - нет, не уникальный. / Если в `C` действительно нужен `A`, то следует использовать _композицию_ вместо _наследования_. Создать экземпляр `A` и вызывать его методы/свойства.

Comment: Этот код не компилируется, у вас кириллица в названии класса `С : В` (Эс : Вэ)

Comment: @aepot, разве кириллицу нельзя использовать в качестве имени?

Comment: @Grundy можно, но когда класс называется B, а наследуешься ты от В, то ничего не соберется.

Comment: @aepot, ага, не увидел, что у него оба класса не такие